# Permission denied (for entry point) on container start

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, docker

Since a few days, I can't run any docker containers on my machine (Ubuntu 18.04). Whenever I try to run/start a container, I receive an error which says that the entrypoint file can't be executed:

```
$ sudo docker run --name test nginx
sh: 0: Can't open /docker-entrypoint.sh
```

or

```
$ docker run --name test2 mongo:4.0
WARNING: Error loading config file: /home/myUser/.docker/config.json: stat /home/myUser/.docker/config.json: permission denied
/bin/bash: /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: Permission denied
```

The second error message leads me to the conclusion, that I might have access problem to the whole docker VM. So, this is the current permission setting on the `.docker` folder:

```
$ sudo ls -l /home/myUser/.docker
total 4
drwx------ 5 root root 4096 Nov 21  2019 machine
```

From my point of view, it should be fine (at least when the docker run/start command is executed as superuser...). Hence, it must be somewhere else. **<= WRONG!** (Edited: No warning should be ignored, even less one where an error is indicaed...)

What I tried/consulted so far:

- reinstall docker => worked fine until the next reboot...
- [this post](https://github.com/composer/docker/issues/7) for permission issues when the entrypoint file is copied into the container from the host (which doesn't apply to my case where no pre-built image is started...)
- desperately scraping the web for other relevant posts without luck

I'm open to any suggestions and would be glad to deliver further details about my setting if necessary.

---

Edit: I followed the [instructions on docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#install-using-the-repository) for the installation and used `apt-get`.

I don't get any results when executing `env | grep DOCKER`...

Below the result of docker info:

```
$ docker info
WARNING: Error loading config file: /home/myUser/.docker/config.json: stat /home/myUser/.docker/config.json: permission denied
Client:
 Debug Mode: false

Server:
 Containers: 9
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 9
 Images: 21
 Server Version: 19.03.11
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 7ad184331fa3e55e52b890ea95e65ba581ae3429
 runc version: 
 init version: fec3683
 Security Options:
  apparmor
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 5.3.0-53-generic
 Operating System: Ubuntu Core 16
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 4
 Total Memory: 15.54GiB
 Name: my-laptop
 ID: ****:****:some:code
 Docker Root Dir: /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Edit 2 (or rather a fun fact): I can run the hello-world example from docker. So, the problem is that the permission inside the docker container aren't enough... why?

Edit 3: Thanks to @Sysadmin, I could remove the warning during the load of `config.json` by following the instructions of [this post](https://askubuntu.com/q/747778/1095641)

Edit 4: Interesting to see, is that a simple image created by myself works fine. Below the example content I used:

```
FROM alpine
CMD ls -l /
```

Comment: How is docker installed? Docker machine, snap, from ubuntu repo, or from docker repo? Do you have multiple docker installs? Is your environment changing between reboots (`env | grep DOCKER`)? Do you have apparmor installed/configured?

Comment: @BMitch, thanks a lot for all the questions. I updated my post by providing at the bottom the demanded information.
I noticed, that I don't get any results when executing `env | grep DOCKER`. Thus, I assume there is/was an installation problem. I will once again reinstall docker...

Comment: @BMitch, after reinstalling I can still not yet run another container except the hello-world example.  So, the problem is most probably really linked to access rights to the VM?

Comment: By default, there shouldn't be any docker env vars, unless you're using something like docker-machine. That check was ruling out talking to different docker instances before/after reboot. There is no VM between docker and the host when you install directly on Linux.

Comment: @BMitch, you're totaly right. I think, this shows how lost I am...

Comment: Is `docker-entrypoint.sh` executable? If not add `chmod +x docker-entrypoint.sh` in your Dockerfile to make it executable.

Comment: I don't use a specific Dockerfile. I'm trying to use one from dockerhub.io like the one from [nginx](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/). Which worked without any issues in the past. So, I don't really know where to make the change the permission as you suggested, except by downloading the Dockerfile and add the line `RUN chmod +x /docker-entrypoint.sh` to the end. But when building the image, I'm getting another error (before reaching the statement above) at Step 6:
`+ addgroup --system --gid 101 nginx`
`Can't open perl script "/usr/sbin/addgroup": Permission denied`

Comment: Check what you're doing against this [article](https://www.nginx.com/blog/deploying-nginx-nginx-plus-docker/).

Comment: @harrymc This doesn't work. This isn't a particular problem with nginx, I'm getting the same error when taking other images such as mongo:4.0. But I tried once to create a simple docker image myself and it seems to work. I added the content to my post.

Comment: For general omissions: Have you added your user (who has root privileges) to docker group?  See also this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/747778/docker-warning-config-json-permission-denied).

Comment: @harrymc Yes, I did. I can see my user when executing `grep docker /etc/group`

Comment: What are the permissions on `/home/myUser`? Do they permit traversal by `root`? It looks like it.

I note that in your `sudo ls -l /home/myUser/.docker` there is no `config.json`. I have a relatively vanilla Ubuntu 18 with docker and there is a `config.json` in my `~/.docker`. Perhaps [create one](https://success.docker.com/article/generate-new-auth-in-config-json-file)?

Comment: @0xACE, I followed the instructions to create a `confis.json` file and it DID THE TRICK! I can't even remember having setup an account at docker before... However, please post it as an answer for me to accept it.

Comment: @Uchendu done, below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `sudo ls -l /home/myUser/.docker` there is no `config.json`.

I have a relatively vanilla Ubuntu 18 with docker and there is a `config.json` in my `~/.docker`. Try and [create one](https://success.docker.com/article/generate-new-auth-in-config-json-file) to eliminate the warning and see of the error goes away as a result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy the bash script file in the location where the VM can access the file, preferably globally like so:

```
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I don't create a `docker-entrypoint.sh` file myself. Hence, I assume it should be copied to the right directory by the Dockerfile of the images I used (e.g. nginx). Please correct me if I misunderstood something or elaborate a little bite more where I should find the `docker-entrypoint.sh` file etc.

Comment: Here you have the explanation. I corrected my answer not cp by COPY.
https://success.docker.com/article/use-a-script-to-initialize-stateful-container-data
Let me know did it solve the issue.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the proposal. This does not solve my problem since I'm not writing the dockerfile myself. I pull the images directly from dockerhub, so there is no place I could use your command, except if I would rewrite a Dockerfile

Comment: Check additionally this https://askubuntu.com/questions/747778/docker-warning-config-json-permission-denied

Comment: This helped to remove the warning when loading the `config.json` file. Thanks a lot! However, the main problem of not being able to run/start a container remains

Comment: what commands
docker run --name test2 mongo:4.0 
sudo ls -l /home/myUser/.docker
show now?

Comment: If you would like to use Docker as a non-root user, you should now consider adding your user to the “docker” group with something like:

  sudo usermod -aG docker your-user

Comment: Also I need :
systemctl status docker.service
sudo docker daemon -D
./check-config.sh output
See this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37227349/unable-to-start-docker-service-in-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109477/discussion-between-uchendu-and-sysadmin).

Comment: Excuse me, but I do not have time to chat.

Comment: Sure, no worries. It's actually only to prevent an to many comments on your post and to post the output of the commands you asked me to execute.